# In what way are Clojure maps functions?

Tags: function, clojure

In his talk ["Maybe not"](https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/MaybeNot.md) Rich Hickey states:

> maps are (mathematical) functions!
>
> in Clojure, we can directly write, and invoke
>
> ({:a 1 :b 2} :b)  =>  2

However I have the feeling that they are not in fact first class Clojure functions, or are they?

I can call the map with a keyword, or the other way around:

```
user=> (:b {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
2
user=> ({:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} :b)
2
```

But I can't use apply either way it seems:

```
user=> (apply #(:b %) {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: user/eval1762/fn--1763  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)

user=> (apply #({:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} %) :b)
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

And neither can I apply the keyword directly to the map:

```
user=> (apply {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} :b)
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

So are they functions only in the mathematical sense, or is there more to them in the sense of applying a keyword similar to a "normal" clojure function?

Comment: If you use `(apply #((fn [x] x) %) :b)` or `(apply #(:b %) (fn [x] x))` to substitute an explicit 1-arity function in the places where you're currently passing maps, you get the same errors -- demonstrating that the problem is not about maps' function-ness, but about the usage patterns themselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maps *are* functions of keys, as in your first two examples. Maps implement `IFn` interface just like "regular" Clojure functions.

The reason [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) doesn't work in your examples is due to the "sequence" arguments being passed in the second position.

```
(apply #(:b %) {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
```

In that example, the map argument is being turned into a sequence of key/value vectors/tuples, so they can be *applied* to `#(:b %)` (which wouldn't work anyway because that anonymous function only takes one argument). This is how the map would look as it's being turned into a sequence and applied as arguments to the function:

```
user=> (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3])
```

This second example doesn't work because `:b` is not a sequence — it's a single keyword. This works though:

```
user=> (apply {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:b])
2
```

Note that calling a map-as-function with `apply` and a sequence of keywords doesn't really make practical sense though.

Answer (score 8):

A [mathematical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a set of ordered pairs such that there are no distinct pairs with the same first element. A mathematical function so defined takes only one argument.

Clojure maps are self-evidently *mathematical* functions, since the there are no distinct key-value pairs with the same key. Moreover, Clojure maps have a finite domain (set of `keys`) and range/co-domain (set of `values`).

As [@TaylorWood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55301735/1562315) has stated, Clojure maps are *Clojure* functions because they implement [clojure.lang.IFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java). They do so as operators yielding the value for a given key, so consistent with their interpretation as mathematical functions.

Your `apply` syntax is wrong. You can write

```
user=> (apply {:a 1, :b 2} [:a])
1
```

or

```
user=> (apply {:a 1, :b 2} :a []) 
1
```

You can supply some of the arguments for the function (the first argument to `apply`) inline. The remainder comprise the sequence that is the last argument to `apply`. Since there is exactly one argument here, we can put it inline or alone in the terminal sequence.

Similar considerations apply to the use of keywords as arguments.

---

**Reply to @AlanThompson's comments**

1. I've listened to and read [Rich's talk](https://github.com/matthiasn/talk-transcripts/blob/master/Hickey_Rich/MaybeNot.md) that the question refers to. My definition of a function agrees with his.
2. My statement that *"A mathematical function **so defined** takes only one argument"* is self evidently correct.
3. You could contend that my definition isn't the conventional one. But even that is false. If you read the [Multivariate_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Multivariate_function) part of the Wikipedia article we both refer to, you will find

> More formally, a function of n variables is a function whose domain is
>   a set of n-tuples
>
> ...
>
> When using function notation, one usually omits the parentheses
>   surrounding tuples, writing `f(x1 , x2)` instead of `f((x1 , x 2))`.

In other words, the idea that a (mathematical) function takes several arguments is a harmless informality that allows simpler notation.

Where does that leave programming languages? Most of them have functions of any arity: in Clojure's case, any finite set of arities, including an infinite one.

The simplest way to regard Clojure functions is that they take an inline sequence of arguments, perhaps an empty one. It would be possible to formulate mathematical functions in this way: mappings from sequences of things to things. **But it just isn't done**.

Comment: Many functions in math take more than 1 arg:  `z=2x+3y` being a simple example.

Comment: @AlanThompson In that case, the first element in your order pair would simply be another ordered pair -- i.e., ((x,y), z)

Comment: It is not that simple. 6 DOF models for aircraft, motorcycles, etc measure both position & rotation (x2) in 3D (x3), and may include derivatives 0, 1 and 2 (x3).  That makes 18 input arguments to a function!

Comment: @AlanThompson That is quite simple, mathematically. The function is a set of ordered pairs whose first element are 18-tuples. Unpleasant and offensive to you as a programmer, but nothing wrong with it in theory. All functions, of any number of arguments, can be viewed in this way.

Comment: I am simply trying to refute the incorrect statement, *"A mathematical function so defined takes only one argument"*.  This will mislead people.  A generalized function takes N inputs and produces M outputs:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Arrow_notation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the practical goal of this question is, but it is interesting from an academic point of view.

The keyword "function" `:b` in the following is a function of 1 argument:

```
(:b {:a 1 :b 2})  => 2
```

It is like this function:

```
(defn get-b [m] (get m :b)) ; takes a single map arg

(get-b {:a 3 :b 33})  ; only 1 arg, so no problem
   => 33
```

The special form `apply` ***re-writes the function call*** from having a single collection argument to having multiple, individual args.  Comparing before & after we get:

```
(apply some-fn [1 2 3] )  ; using  apply
      (some-fn  1 2 3  )  ; without apply (note missing square brackets!)
```

So, `apply` allows you to "spread" args from a collection ***as if*** you had typed them as separate, individual args in the function call. If your collection has only 1 element, using apply has little effect:

```
(apply :b [{:a 3 :b 33}] ) ; a collection of 1 element
      (:b  {:a 3 :b 33}  ) ; only 1 arg, so no problem
```

Because the function :b takes only 1 arg, the following won't work:

```
(apply #(:b %) [{:a 1 :b 11} {:a 2 :b 22} {:a 3 :b 33}])  ; takes only 1 arg, not 3 args
```

However, you can invoke the 1-arg function `:b` multiple times using `map` or `mapv`:

```
(mapv :b [{:a 1 :b 11} {:a 2 :b 22} {:a 3 :b 33}])  ; takes only 1 arg, not 3 args

   => [11 22 33]
```

The same rules hold for the inverse case. A map like `{:a 1 :b 2}` is a function of 1 argument, so it can't be invoked with 3 args:

```
(apply {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3} [:c :b :a])  ; 3 args to single-arg fn, so fails
```

but this works fine:

```
(mapv {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3} [:c :b :a]) => [3 2 1]
```

Comment: [`apply`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L652) isn't a true [special form](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms), and maps aren't _only_ unary functions; they can take a second arg for default value: `({:foo 1} :bar 2) => 2`